# Polymer click re-route on iOS

Tags: ios, safari, polymer

I'm using a hidden 
    `<input id="mfile" type="file" accept="image/*">`
and triggering it with a paper-fab from google's element catalog. It works everywhere except for safari on iOS, the click fires but it doesn't get redirected to the input.

By redirect i mean a on-tap listener on the fab that triggers `this.$.mfile.click();`

Any suggestion or workaround?

Comment: `Safari on iOS` is same as `Safari on Mac OS`. You can debug it in the Mac OS and check the errors there.

Comment: I thought so, but it works on safari for mac, so it looks like they're not the same. Also the debugger gives me no errors

Comment: Same here.. and yes, it's only on iOS, not only Safari btw, is the same with Chrome. It works just fine in Mac and Android.

Comment: I have the same problem. I've tried ensuring the function triggered by the `on-tap` handler calls `this.$.file.click()`, but it doesn't work for me either.

Comment: Just so you know.. placing the input file inside your fab works. Though I'm not a fan of that solution, but it could work for you.

Comment: Is it on Simulator as well, you can debug using the `Safari Technology Preview`. https://webkit.org/blog/6017/introducing-safari-technology-preview/.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to @marx_tseng from polymer slack, here is the solution:
https://polymer.slack.com/archives/general/p1478229319019481

```
<paper-fab id="fileFab" label="File" on-tap="_pickFile"></paper-fab>
<input type="file" id="filePicker" hidden />
```

...

```
_pickFile: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.$.fileFab.blur();

    // cancelable is true, not work on ios simulator
    // this.$.filePicker.click();

    // default cancelable is false, work on ios simulator
    try {
        // fixes mobile safari
        var evt = new MouseEvent("click");
        this.$.filePicker.dispatchEvent(evt);
    } catch (e) {
        // fallback for IE11
        this.$.filePicker.click();
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, perfect. Thank you :)

Comment: `var evt = new MouseEvent("click");` does not work in IE11 for me, so I wrapped it in a try/catch and did `this.$.filePicker.click()` inside the catch. Working great now. Thanks again!

Comment: nice.. thanks for the update @jpodwys .. could you please go ahead and edit the answer?

Comment: Yes, sorry I didn't think of it.